# How to Delete row/rows in sqlite (java, not Android java)

Tags: java, sqlite, sql-delete

Need to delete records from sqlite db.  One record row at a time and/or all records with a particular string value.
I read many posts and most seem to be for Android and very different from plain Java - didn't find what I need.

Here's the code snippet I'm trying (delString comes in from a textfield), I did not set up record ID's.:

```
    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:dufuss.db");

    delIt = Dialog_RecToDelete.delString; 
    String sql = "DELETE * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE docName = ?";
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    preparedStatement.setString(1, delIt);
    ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

    while (rs.next()) {
      // iterate through results
    }
  rs.close();
  conn.close();
```

Comment: use [`PreparedStatement#executeUpdate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate%28%29)

Comment: did not work - tried it before posting.  Get message:   near "*": syntax error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_delete.html), it should just be `DELETE FROM ...`, so remove the `*` in `DELETE * FROM ...`.

Also, you should use [`PreparedStatement#executeUpdate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate%28%29) instead of `PreparedStatement#executeQuery`

Comment: Pefect! - it works!  (deletes the row whose first column contain the delString value - just as I needed).

Answer (score 2):

SQLite is light also on the syntax, they do not use the `*` as it's unnecessary (Who only deletes a column only and not the entire row?).

So, the following syntax should work:

```
"DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE docName = ?"
```

Also note, as @damo commented, that you need to use `executeUpdate()` instead of `executeQuery()` and possibly a commit is in order if it's not auto-commiting.

More info on DELETE syntax [here](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_delete.html).